# How does R+W > N makes sense for large clusters?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, eventual-consistency

Say I have a 50 node cluster and my replication factor = 3 and Write 
Consistency Level = Quorum which is (50/2) + 1 = 26 and Read Consistency Level = ONE. Now we satisfy the equation R + W > N because 26 + 1 > 3 but how does this guarantee strong consistency? what if my write goes to first 26 nodes and I happen to read from node 45. How can I get the most updated value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consistency Level = The number of acknowledgements that **REPLICA** nodes need to give the coordinator in order to satisfy a request.

So in your example, `CL=QUORUM = 2` because 2 is the majority of RF = 3.

Plugging that back into the equation... `2 + 1 = 3` `3 !> 3` there for you don't have 100% consistency.

See: http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_config_consistency_c.html